# how to remove laravel vapor cloudfront public assets caches on fresh deployment

Tags: laravel, amazon-cloudfront, laravel-vapor

I have a **Laravel** and **VueJs** application. I recently migrated the application to **Laravel Vapor**.
I am using **webpack** code splitting feature.

https://docs.vapor.build/1.0/projects/deployments.html#code-splitting-dynamic-imports

The problem is, whenever I push new changes to **vapor**, any change that I have made related to **VueJs/Javascript**, doesn't reflects in the new deployment.

As per my understanding, the problem might be due to CloudFront Cache as vapor moves all public assets to CloudFront or it might be something else.

Please let me know, how can fix this.

Thanks

Comment: When vapor deploys your assets end up at a new url so that should not be happening. It will not be a cloudfront cache issue. Are you using the asset helper?

Comment: @BobB yes I am using the asset helper.

Answer (score 1):

It was due to my mistake in the code. I was using the wrong CloudFront URL, it was hardcoded in .env **ASSET_URL** but **Vapor** generates a new URL on each fresh deployment and automatically injects it in **.env** file and that we have to use as per docs https://docs.vapor.build/1.0/projects/deployments.html#assets

Thanks